# Output of a program on compilation

Tags: c

I have two questions.  I would have put them seperately but the first one is just really small.

Question1) Is it true that if the return type of a function is not specified, it defaults to int?

Question2) What error will the following function give on compilation?

```
f( int a, int b )
{
    int a;
    a = 20;
    return a;
}
```

The options are:

```
1.) Missing parentheses in return statement.
2.) The function should be defined as int f( int a, int b )
3.) Redeclaration of a
4.) None of the above
```

According to me, the answer should be both 2) and 3).

But it gives the answer only as 2). Why is that so?

Thanks.:)

Comment: IMHO the correct aswer is to specify into which standard you are refering (K&R C, C89, C99). For example for first question answer may be yes or no.

Comment: IF ( capitalised especially because it is not mentioned in the question ) I TAKE IT TO BE C99, what will be the answer for the second part?

Comment: @user3797829: Ouah answered that question for C89, C99 and C11. The only thing unanswered is 1. and the answer is no (for all of the three standards), because a `return` statement doesn't need parenthesis around its expression (as opposed to example given the `if` statement).

Comment: @user3797829: 1) parentheses are not needed, so no 2) yes (as of return type have to be explicite in C99), 3) yes, as `a` is already declared in block scope (of function), 4) no because of 2) and 3)

Comment: So, the final answer will be 2 and 3, right?
( Asking because the answer key says only 2 ).

Comment: @user3797829: For third option see C99 6.9.1 Function definitions, p. 9 (emphasis mine): "Each parameter has automatic storage duration. Its identifier is an lvalue, which is in effect declared at the head of the compound statement that constitutes the function body (and therefore **cannot be redeclared** in the function body except in an enclosed block). The layout of the storage for parameters is unspecified."

Answer (score 5):

*Question1) Is it true that if the return type of a function is not specified, it defaults to int?*

Yes, it was the case in c89. But this feature is no longer supported in c99 and c11. This explains why now in C you have to use `int f(int a, int b)`.

The C Committee explained in the C99 Rationale document (emphasis mine):

> "A new feature of C99: In C89, all type    specifiers could be omitted from the declaration specifiers in a declaration. In such a case int was implied. The Committee decided that the inherent danger of this feature outweighed its convenience, and **so it was removed**. The effect is to guarantee the production of a diagnostic that will catch an additional category of programming errors."

Answer (score 0):

My answers:
for the first question : no, its not true. in C language you must specify the return type. if you don't need to return anything you specify it as : void .
for the second question : second choice 2. is true.

Comment: 1) it depends on the version of the C language 2) it depends on the version of the C language.